# PowerShell SNMP query for supported languages

Tags: powershell, snmp, printers

I'm having some difficulty to retrieve the SNMP information for a printer when using `GetTree`. In the code below I would like to retrieve the values for the field `..prtLocalizationLanguage.1.x`. Populated in the property `Language` like 'en, fr, it, ...'.

```
$PrinterName = '10.10.10.1', 'Printer2'

Function Get-SNMPInfoHC {
    Param (
        [String[]]$PrinterName
    )
    Begin {
        $SNMP = New-Object -ComObject olePrn.OleSNMP
    }
    Process {
        Foreach ($P in $PrinterName) {
            $SNMP.Open($P,"public",2,3000)
            [PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
                Name        = $SNMP.Get(".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5.0")
                Model       = $SNMP.Get(".1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.2.1.3.1")
                Contact     = $SNMP.Get(".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0")
                SN          = $SNMP.Get(".1.3.6.1.2.1.43.5.1.1.17.1")
                Description = $SNMP.Get(".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0")
                Location    = $SNMP.Get(".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0")
                UpTime      = [TimeSpan]::FromSeconds(($SNMP.Get(".1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0"))/100)
                TonerName   = $SNMP.Get("43.11.1.1.6.1.1")
                Languages   = $SNMP.GetTree(".1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7")
            }
            $SNMP.Close()
        }
    }
}    
Get-SNMPInfoHC $PrinterName
```

The output of the `Language` part looks as following:

```
$SNMP.GetTree(".1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1") 
printmib.prtLocalization.prtLocalizationTable.prtLocalizationEntry.prtLocalizationLanguage.1.1
printmib.prtLocalization.prtLocalizationTable.prtLocalizationEntry.prtLocalizationLanguage.1.2
printmib.prtLocalization.prtLocalizationTable.prtLocalizationEntry.prtLocalizationLanguage.1.3
printmib.prtLocalization.prtLocalizationTable.prtLocalizationEntry.prtLocalizationLanguage.1.4
printmib.prtLocalization.prtLocalizationTable.prtLocalizationEntry.prtLocalizationCountry.1.1
printmib.prtLocalization.prtLocalizationTable.prtLocalizationEntry.prtLocalizationCountry.1.2
printmib.prtLocalization.prtLocalizationTable.prtLocalizationEntry.prtLocalizationCountry.1.3
printmib.prtLocalization.prtLocalizationTable.prtLocalizationEntry.prtLocalizationCountry.1.4
printmib.prtLocalization.prtLocalizationTable.prtLocalizationEntry.prtLocalizationCharacterSet.1.1
printmib.prtLocalization.prtLocalizationTable.prtLocalizationEntry.prtLocalizationCharacterSet.1.2
printmib.prtLocalization.prtLocalizationTable.prtLocalizationEntry.prtLocalizationCharacterSet.1.3
printmib.prtLocalization.prtLocalizationTable.prtLocalizationEntry.prtLocalizationCharacterSet.1.4
en
fr
it
de
US
FR
IT
DE
2001
2001
2001
2001
```

Is there a way to only retrieve the values for `prtLocalizationLanguage`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not familiar with the language or the library you're using, but can give some advice about SNMP.

It seems like you've simply confused the OIDs a bit. Your code fetches the subtree `1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7` using `GetTree`. That subtree is named `prtLocalization` and is a parent of the variable you want. (You can see the whole MIB tree printed at [this web page](http://www.multinet.de/fileadmin/mib2/rfc1759.html).)

The variable you're actually after is `1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.2`, a.k.a `prtLocalizationLanguage`. It is the second column of the table `prtLocalizationTable`.

The way tables work in SNMP is such that each value in that column is reached by appending an index to the column OID. Like so:

- 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.2 **.1**
- 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.2 **.2**
- 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.2 **.3** etc.

It follows that the easiest way to fetch only the values in that column is to do an SNMP `walk` operation on the column header (i.e. 1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.2). Most likely, this is done by simply plugging that OID into the `GetTree()` call:

```
Languages   = $SNMP.GetTree(".1.3.6.1.2.1.43.7.1.1.2")
en
fr
it
de
```